# When could the user's Locale.current.region be nil?

Tags: ios, swift, foundation

The [locale region](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/3952525-region) is optional from Foundation. It is my understanding that this property is read from the device under `iOS Settings > General > Language & Region > Region`.

What is the possible scenarios that the region property is `nil`; why is it optional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is my understanding that this property is read from the device under `iOS Settings > General > Language & Region > Region`

Well, that would be `Locale.current`, but that is not the only instance of `Locale` instance there can be. You can create your own locales.

More accurately, [`region`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/locale/3952525-region) is:

> This property corresponds to the rg key of the Unicode BCP 47 extension.
> For locale instances created with the rg specifier (such as `en-GB@rg=US`), or with a custom `Locale.Components`, this property represents the custom region. Otherwise, it represents the language’s region.

I tried setting `Locale.Components.region` to nil, but the `Locale` created this way still has the default region of the language:

```
var components = Locale.Components(languageCode: .english)
components.region = nil
let locale = Locale(components: components)
print(locale.region) // US
```

If the `Locale.Language` does not belong to any region though, then `region` would be nil. And such `Locale.Language`s do exist! For example:

```
// zxx - no linguistic content
let unidentified = Locale(languageCode: .unidentified)
print(unidentified.region) // nil

// mul - multiple languages
let multiple = Locale(languageCode: .multiple)
print(multiple.region) // nil
```

So `region` has to be optional *at least* because of the `mul` and `zxx` "languages", as required in BCP 47.